# Windows 10/11, Manjaro Dual Boot: WIndows lagging, freezing not booting and suddeny windows partitions missing

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, grub, ahci

My PC has quite a view issues, and already a view Problem fixes couldn't resolve the issue.
Also symptoms varied a bit over time from OS-lags, to OS-freezes, to getting this crapmachine to boot.
So It's gonna be a bit of a read my dear viewer.

Machine Stats (Grub Dualboot):

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- RAM: 16GB dual slot
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3070

Motherboard:

- SSD_1: nvme M.2 Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500GB with Manjaro Linux
- SSD_2: SATA Samsung 860 EVO 500GB Windows 10/11

ca. 2 months ago
At the beginning, whith a win10/manjaro dualboot, windows sometimes got laggy.

This laggynes increased in intensity starting from anoying but with no real impact on useability to work interrupting to sometimes making it impossible to work to finally freezing the windows UI completely.
At this point I tried my first fix:

In a StackOverflow(Or similar website) post, I sadly couldn't find now in a quick search, It was recommended to change some specific "AHCI Link Power Management" Setting on the Windows SSD.
Sadly I can't remember that one either.
This fixed for a while until the next thing went wrong

starting two weeks ago:
My PC sometimes wouldn't boot into windows after selecting it in GRUB.
This didn't first also happened rarely but inevitably this problem also increased in frequency.
Then I decided to fix it once and for all with the good old windows way:

one week ago:
I made a complete reset of Windows 10 with the windows reset feature in the startup repair menu.
then when this was finished and I also upgraded to win 11 in the hopes, that this maybe is some not well known that microsoft fixed silently with the new version.
Weeelll nooo windows don't work like that....

The new install worked for a few days until it didn't manage to boot this bloated ****peace of OS anymore.
I again only got to the GRUB menu which detected windows, but then windows wouldn't boot anymore and randomly giving me different error messages:

[errormsg1 at boot, when pressing a Key I return to the GRUB menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTmlj.jpg)

[errormsg2 -''-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QC8a.jpg)

[errormsg3 -''-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gndfe.jpg)

Sporadically i get it to run only to watch as it freezed for no single f*ing reason.
I also tried deactivating the windows fast boot option, which didn't work at all.

The Linux side of the system worked like a charm the whole time.
The last thing I did was to check If I can copy some valueable data from the windows ssd and then I noticed that the windows partitions are not even showing up anymore on the linux side:

```
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
run             7,8G  1,8M  7,8G   1% /run
efivarfs        128K   38K   86K  31% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2  441G  335G   84G  81% /
tmpfs           7,8G   64M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/loop7      128K  128K     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop8      816M  816M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/298
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop6       66M   66M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop9      818M  818M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/306
/dev/loop4       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1026
/dev/loop0      100M  100M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11420
/dev/loop1      100M  100M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11606
/dev/loop5       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1081
tmpfs           7,8G  3,4M  7,8G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M  312K  300M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   88K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ fdisk -l
fdisk: cannot open /dev/nvme0n1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop7: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop8: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop9: Permission denied
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for user:  
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 96EC97F6-7F1E-564F-96EC-BE29D9B79763

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      4096    618495    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    618496 940729203 940110708 448,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 940729204 976768064  36038861  17,2G Linux swap


Disk /dev/loop0: 99,38 MiB, 104210432 bytes, 203536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 99,34 MiB, 104169472 bytes, 203456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55,44 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 55,44 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 61,73 MiB, 64729088 bytes, 126424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 61,77 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 65,1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 20 KiB, 20480 bytes, 40 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 815,64 MiB, 855257088 bytes, 1670424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 817,91 MiB, 857640960 bytes, 1675080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  99,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11420
loop1         7:1    0  99,3M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11606
loop2         7:2    0  55,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2074
loop3         7:3    0  55,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2128
loop4         7:4    0  61,7M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1026
loop5         7:5    0  61,8M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1081
loop6         7:6    0  65,1M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop7         7:7    0    20K  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29
loop8         7:8    0 815,6M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/298
loop9         7:9    0 817,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/306
sda           8:0    0     0B  0 disk  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 448,3G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  17,2G  0 part [SWAP]
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ cfdisk
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ sudo cfdisk
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Invalid argument
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ sudo cfdisk
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Invalid argument
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 96EC97F6-7F1E-564F-96EC-BE29D9B79763

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      4096    618495    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    618496 940729203 940110708 448,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 940729204 976768064  36038861  17,2G Linux swap


Disk /dev/loop0: 99,38 MiB, 104210432 bytes, 203536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 99,34 MiB, 104169472 bytes, 203456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55,44 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 55,44 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 61,73 MiB, 64729088 bytes, 126424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 61,77 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 65,1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 20 KiB, 20480 bytes, 40 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 815,64 MiB, 855257088 bytes, 1670424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 817,91 MiB, 857640960 bytes, 1675080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven ~]$ cd /dev
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven dev]$ ls
autofs           hidraw1    loop2             nvme0      stdout  tty24  tty43  tty62   ttyS23   userfaultfd  vcsu
block            hidraw2    loop3             nvme0n1    tpm0    tty25  tty44  tty63   ttyS24   userio       vcsu1
bsg              hidraw3    loop4             nvme0n1p1  tpmrm0  tty26  tty45  tty7    ttyS25   v4l          vcsu2
btrfs-control    hpet       loop5             nvme0n1p2  tty     tty27  tty46  tty8    ttyS26   vboxdrv      vcsu3
bus              hugepages  loop6             nvme0n1p3  tty0    tty28  tty47  tty9    ttyS27   vboxdrvu     vcsu4
char             hwrng      loop7             nvram      tty1    tty29  tty48  ttyS0   ttyS28   vboxnetctl   vcsu5
console          i2c-0      loop8             port       tty10   tty3   tty49  ttyS1   ttyS29   vboxusb      vcsu6
core             i2c-1      loop9             ppp        tty11   tty30  tty5   ttyS10  ttyS3    vcs          vfio
cpu              i2c-2      loop-control      psaux      tty12   tty31  tty50  ttyS11  ttyS30   vcs1         vga_arbiter
cpu_dma_latency  i2c-3      mapper            ptmx       tty13   tty32  tty51  ttyS12  ttyS31   vcs2         vhci
cuse             i2c-4      media0            pts        tty14   tty33  tty52  ttyS13  ttyS4    vcs3         vhost-net
disk             i2c-5      mem               random     tty15   tty34  tty53  ttyS14  ttyS5    vcs4         vhost-vsock
dma_heap         i2c-6      mqueue            rfkill     tty16   tty35  tty54  ttyS15  ttyS6    vcs5         video0
dri              i2c-7      net               rtc        tty17   tty36  tty55  ttyS16  ttyS7    vcs6         video1
fb0              i2c-8      ng0n1             rtc0       tty18   tty37  tty56  ttyS17  ttyS8    vcsa         watchdog
fd               input      null              sda        tty19   tty38  tty57  ttyS18  ttyS9    vcsa1        watchdog0
full             kmsg       nvidia0           shm        tty2    tty39  tty58  ttyS19  udmabuf  vcsa2        zero
fuse             kvm        nvidiactl         snapshot   tty20   tty4   tty59  ttyS2   uhid     vcsa3
gpiochip0        log        nvidia-modeset    snd        tty21   tty40  tty6   ttyS20  uinput   vcsa4
gpiochip1        loop0      nvidia-uvm        stderr     tty22   tty41  tty60  ttyS21  urandom  vcsa5
hidraw0          loop1      nvidia-uvm-tools  stdin      tty23   tty42  tty61  ttyS22  usb      vcsa6
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven dev]$ ls sda*
sda
[user@HighEndMicrowaveOven dev]$
```

PS.: I hope this is enough Info, If not please tell me what you need.
And Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Boot **from USB**, e.g., Live Linux. 2. Salvage all you can, e.g., dd disk image. 3. Check all files systems and drive health -- likely failing.

Comment: Can you recommend any programs to check file systems and drive health?

Comment: A live/installation Manjaro media has all the tools you need.